# C# Drawing multiple charts in real time

Tags: c#, forms, charts, real-time

I have a acquistion device that reads data and adds it to the buffer. This is done in a separate thread. Once this data is dequeued, I set up a delegate that raise the event OnDataRead().

In my signal monitor, when the event is received I want to plot the data in multiple charts (16 in total). I sucessfully plot the first samples but then charts stop plotting data, starting from the 16th and progressively stopping all of them. What would be the correct way of doing that? Do I need a separate thread?

Receives event with data

```
    public void OnDataRead(object source, DataEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.rawData.Length > 0)
        {
            AddData(e.rawData, e.numChannels, e.triggerEnabled);
        }
    }
```

Add datapoints in the appropiate chart

```
 private void AddData(float[] rawData, int numChannels, bool triggerEnabled)
    {
        //for (int i=0; i<chChannels.Count; i++)
       // {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetAddDataCallback d = new SetAddDataCallback(AddData);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] {rawData, numChannels, triggerEnabled})
                    ;
            }
            else
            {
                DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.Now;

                // Find the channel selected
                int channelIdx = 0; //boxChannelSelection.SelectedIndex;
                // Add new data points for the selected channel
                for (int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < rawData.Length; sampleIdx++)
                {
                    channelIdx = sampleIdx %(numChannels + 1);

                    if (triggerEnabled && (channelIdx != numChannels))
                    {
                        foreach (Series ptSeries in chChannels[channelIdx].Series)
                        {
                            AddNewPoint(timeStamp, rawData[sampleIdx], channelIdx, ptSeries);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!triggerEnabled)
                    {
                        foreach (Series ptSeries in chChannels[channelIdx].Series)
                        {
                            AddNewPoint(timeStamp, rawData[sampleIdx], channelIdx, ptSeries);
                        }

                    }
                    }
                }
           // }
    }
```

Plot new datapoint in the chart

```
 public void AddNewPoint(DateTime timeStamp, float yValue, int channel, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series ptSeries)
        {

            ptSeries.Points.AddXY(timeStamp.ToOADate(), yValue);

            // Remove old datapoints if needed
            double removeBefore = timeStamp.AddSeconds((double)(8) * (-1)).ToOADate();
            while (ptSeries.Points[0].XValue < removeBefore)
            {
                ptSeries.Points.RemoveAt(0);
            }

            chChannels[channel].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = ptSeries.Points[0].XValue;
            chChannels[channel].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.FromOADate(ptSeries.Points[0].XValue).AddSeconds(10).ToOADate();

            chChannels[channel].Invalidate();
```

Comment: When does the plotting stop: Before or after removing the first batch of points? Why do you write `(double)(8) * (-1)` ? Does moving the addxy after the remove change anything?

Comment: I stops before removing the first batch of points. (double)(8) * (-1) is to remove points 8 seconds before the current point, to constantly update the plot.

Comment: I think a good approach is when new data is received, add it to a buffer (linkedlist) and then have a separate thread that every 100ms updates the charts with the data stored in the buffer. What makes it crash is update 16 charts every time new data is received. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good approach to draw the data in the charts in a different thread.

When new data is read, data is stored in a list or array. Since it is real-time data, the timestamps are also generated here. Using the sample rate of the data acquired: timeStamp = timeStamp + sampleIdx/sampleRate;

```
public void OnDataRead(object source, EEGEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.rawData.Length > 0) && (!_shouldStop))
            {
                lock (_bufferRawData)
                {
                    for (int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < e.rawData.Length; sampleIdx++)
                    {
                        // Append data
                        _bufferRawData.Add(e.rawData[sampleIdx]);

                       // Calculate corresponding timestamp
                      secondsToAdd = (float) sampleIdx/e.sampleRate;

                    // Append corresponding timestamp
                    _bufferXValues.Add( e.timeStamp.AddSeconds(secondsToAdd));
                    }
                }
```

Then, create a thread that sleeps every N ms (100ms is suitable for me for a 2 seconds display of data, but if I wanna display 10 seconds, I need to increase to 500ms of sleep time for the thread)

```
 //Create thread
 //define a thread to add values into chart
 ThreadStart addDataThreadObj = new ThreadStart(AddDataThreadLoop);
 _addDataRunner = new Thread(addDataThreadObj);
 addDataDel += new AddDataDelegate(AddData);

 //Start thread
 _addDataRunner.Start();
```

And finally, update the charts and make the thread sleep every N ms

```
 private void AddDataThreadLoop()
    {
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            chChannels[1].Invoke(addDataDel);

            // Sleeep thread for 100ms
            Thread.Sleep(100); 
        }
    }
```

Data will be added to the chart every 100ms

```
private void AddData()
    {
        // Copy data stored in lists to arrays
        float[] rawData;
        DateTime[] xValues;

            if (_bufferRawData.Count > 0)
            {
                // Copy buffered data in thread-safe manner
                lock (_bufferRawData)
                {
                    rawData = _bufferRawData.ToArray();
                    _bufferRawData.Clear();
                    xValues = _bufferXValues.ToArray();
                    _bufferXValues.Clear();
                }

                for (int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < rawData.Length; sampleIdx++)
                {
                        foreach (Series ptSeries in chChannels[channelIdx].Series)
                            // Add new datapoint to the corresponding chart (x, y, chartIndex, seriesIndex)
                            AddNewPoint(xValues[sampleIdx], rawData[sampleIdx], ptSeries);
           }
      }
 }
```